# how to validate datetime on laravel validator with date_format rule

Tags: laravel, datetime-format, laravel-validation

[Datetime input on Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4aJV.png)

this my input datetime in form, the format is **30/12/2023 11.52.18**

i want to validate that format with laravel validation rule data_format
i was try on laravel validation rule -> date_format:dd/mm/yyyy h.i.s and its always detect as format not valid

and this my validator in controller
[Validate in Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPA3M.png)

Comment: you can try this required|date_format:d-m-y h.i.s   OR required|date_format:D-m-y h.i.s  OR required|date_format:d-m-y

Comment: @UmerFayyaz still failed bro

Comment: What is your migration table structure if it is $table->dateTime('your_column') you should use 'waktu' => 'required|date' and it should solve the issue